# Using NSMutableArray in TableViewController with JSON data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to use a NSMutableArray in my TableViewController from a JSON output and I'm a little bit lost because currently I can store my JSON data in a NSMutableArray, and I have checked with a NSLog that the content is OK, but now I have to show that data in my TableViewController and that's when I'm lost.

I'm using an another example of TableViewController using NSArray but now I have to modify it for a NSMutableArray. If you can help me with some code or show me some examples or tutorials I will be much appreciated.

I know in my code maybe I have something wrong because I'm using an old example using only NSArray but I'm showing you because that's what I don't know how to do, I need to work with NSMutableArray and that's why I'm asking for your help.

How can I show a NSMutableArray in my TableViewController?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchJson];
}

-(void)fetchJson {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        //NSError * error;
        //NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        // I advice that you make your carModels mutable array and initialise it here,before start working with json
        //self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *carModels=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *carMakes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSMutableArray *carImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        @try
        {
            NSError *error;

            NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:data
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                    error:&error];

            if (error)
            {
                NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

            }
            else
            {

                for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++)
                {
                    NSDictionary * jsonObject = [json objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                    [carImages addObject:imagen];

                    NSDictionary * jsonObject2 = [json objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSString* user = [jsonObject2 objectForKey:@"user"];
                    [carMakes addObject:user];

                    NSDictionary * jsonObject3 = [json objectAtIndex:i];
                    NSString* images = [jsonObject3 objectForKey:@"date"];
                    [carModels addObject:images];
                }

            }
        }
        @catch (NSException * e)
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        }
        @finally
        {
            NSLog(@"finally");
            // That's showing the data "1, 2, 3".
            NSLog(@"models: %@", carModels);
            NSLog(@"makes: %@", carMakes);
            NSLog(@"images: %@", carImages);
        }
    }
    );
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.carModels count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [_carMakes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    cell.modelLabel.text = [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    UIImage *carPhoto = [UIImage imageNamed: [self.carImages objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];

    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowCarDetails"])
    {
        CarDetailViewController *detailViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView
                                    indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.carDetailModel = [[NSArray alloc]
                                               initWithObjects: [self.carMakes
                                                                 objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carModels objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               [self.carImages objectAtIndex:[myIndexPath row]],
                                               nil];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: carModels, carMakes , carImages , these are arrays ?

Comment: What is the need of taking three array , use directly json parsing array to display the data

Comment: Yes, my arrays are carModels, carImages and carMakes. And inside every one of them I stored a list of "id", a list of "images", and a list of "names" to show them in the TableViewController.

Comment: Using single array ! The array contain dictionaries

Comment: You forgot to add `[self.youTableView reloadData]` method in your finally block.

Comment: You are doing for loop to split the Json array to 3 array ! and The three arrays count is not equal (your given row count single array self.carModels) This is not good way ! I will change your method posted check once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare NSMutableArray *jsonArray ; as global

```
-(void)fetchJson {
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        //NSError * error;
        //NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        // I advice that you make your carModels mutable array and initialise it here,before start working with json
        //self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        @try
        {
            NSError *error;
            [jsonArray removeAllObjects];
           jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                                    JSONObjectWithData:data
                                    options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                    error:&error];
        }
        @catch (NSException * e)
        {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        }
        @finally
        {
          [self.tableView reloadData]
        }
    }
    );
}
```

To Display The TableView Like This

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [jsonArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"carTableCell";

    CarTableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CarTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.makeLabel.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"];
    cell.modelLabel.text = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"user"];
    UIImage *carPhoto = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"date"];
    cell.carImage.image = carPhoto;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @srinivas n, I'm going to try it later. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you know where I have to write the code to show a "spinning wheel" like "loading" until everything is loaded? Is it inside the viewdidload? Thanks.

Comment: start the spinner when ever you cal fetchJson method ! and stop and remove the spinner after reloading the table view

Comment: One more your display the image in tableview cell ? this is coming nsdata formate or url ?

Comment: I have posted a new thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810687/using-nsmutablearray-in-tableviewcontroller Can you check it, please? Thanks @srinivas n

Comment: I am asking you display the images in table view ! your need to follow the Lazy loading concept & image is coming  data or url first conform me ! use this for image loading in UITableView cell Check Out https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[self.tableView reloadData]
```

after you have fetched and parsed the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

- Whenever you change table datas from different array just add `[self.tableView reloadData]` in you method.
- It will remove old data & shows new data into your `tableview`.